# add filename to fasta headers in a loop with awk?

Tags: bash, loops, awk, header, fasta

I know this has been asked before but I cannot find a solution that is working - for some reason when I try any of the other solutions posted in stackoverflow they will simply NOT work

I have a directory that has 900+ fasta files, they all finish with ".faa"
some of the names are:

TLLD001.faa TLLD002.faa TLLD003.faa TLLD004.faa TLLD005.faa

etc etc

within each file the headers of the fasta are:

```
   >scaffold4567
   WRVLSTSFNGIKYEQSAAFAMIPSTT
   >scaffold0034
   EQSAAFAMIPSTTSISWRVLSTSFNGIKYEQ
```

or

```
   >NODE_212
   WRVLSTSFNGIKYEQSAAFAMIPSTT
   >NODE_86667
   EQSAAFAMIPSTTSISWRVLSTSFNGIKYEQ
```

etc etc

I wanna go through all the files and replace the header by adding the filename
for example, TLLD001.faa

```
   >scaffold4567
   WRVLSTSFNGIKYEQSAAFAMIPSTT
   >scaffold0034
   EQSAAFAMIPSTTSISWRVLSTSFNGIKYEQ
   >scaffold7667
   WRVLSTSFNGIKYEQSAAFAMIPSTT
   >scaffold6778
   EQSAAFAMIPSTTSISWRVLSTSFNGIKYEQ
```

should become

```
   >TLLD001_scaffold4567
   WRVLSTSFNGIKYEQSAAFAMIPSTT
   >TLLD001_scaffold0034
   EQSAAFAMIPSTTSISWRVLSTSFNGIKYEQ
   >TLLD001_scaffold7667
   WRVLSTSFNGIKYEQSAAFAMIPSTT
   >TLLD001_scaffold6778
   EQSAAFAMIPSTTSISWRVLSTSFNGIKYEQ
```

this is working nicely but i have to specify a single file every time
`$awk '/>/{sub(">","&"FILENAME"_");sub(/\.faa/,x)}1' TLLD001.faa`

so not my cup of tea

this seems to have worked in 3-4 files i did as a test but it will not work in my 900+ files directory -takes forever-

```
for i in *.faa; do 
    sed -i "s/^>/>${i}_/g" *.faa
done
```

and the following are not working at all:

```
$for file in *.fasta; do awk '/^>/ {printf("\n%s\n",$0);next; } { printf("%s",$0);}  END {printf("\n");}' < $file > "`basename $file .fasta`_single-line.fasta"; done
```

and

```
$for file in *.faa; do awk '/>/{sub(">","&"${file}"_");sub(/\.faa/,x)}1' < $file > "`basename $file .faa`_mod.faa"; done
```

and I don't know why! any help and explanation of how to use this almighty but cryptic "awk" will be highly appreciated

thanks
P

Comment: Could you please cover your samples/codes in CODE TAGS, looks like you have used quote tags which is making samples harder to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sed solution is the way to go but you repeated the glob in the command!

Instead of

```
for f in *.faa; do sed -i "s/^>/>${f%.faa}/g" *.faa; done
```

Use the ${f} variable in the sed command, otherwise it is expanded for the sed command again!

```
for f in *.faa; do sed -i "s/^>/>${f%.faa}/g" "${f}"; done
```

I also made us of some bash variable substituion to simply remove .faa from the file.

Comment: you still need to quote `"${f}"`, or simply `"$f"`.

Answer (score 4):

this should do

```
$ for f in *.faa; do sed -i "s/^>/>${f}_/" "$f"; done
```

however will have the file extension inserted as well.  To remove the extension change to `${f%.*}`

Answer (score 1):

Try Perl one-liner.

```
perl -i -0777 -pe ' $x=$ARGV;$x=~s/\.faa//g; s/\>/>${x}_/ ' *faa
```

Here is the break-up

```
$ cat  TLLD001.faa
>scaffold4567
WRVLSTSFNGIKYEQSAAFAMIPSTT
>scaffold0034
EQSAAFAMIPSTTSISWRVLSTSFNGIKYEQ
>scaffold7667
WRVLSTSFNGIKYEQSAAFAMIPSTT
>scaffold6778
EQSAAFAMIPSTTSISWRVLSTSFNGIKYEQ

$ cat TLLD002.faa
>NODE_212
WRVLSTSFNGIKYEQSAAFAMIPSTT
>NODE_86667
EQSAAFAMIPSTTSISWRVLSTSFNGIKYEQ
```

Executing command without in-replace

```
$ perl -0777 -pe ' $x=$ARGV;$x=~s/\.faa//g; s/\>/>${x}_/ ' *faa
>TLLD001_scaffold4567
WRVLSTSFNGIKYEQSAAFAMIPSTT
>scaffold0034
EQSAAFAMIPSTTSISWRVLSTSFNGIKYEQ
>scaffold7667
WRVLSTSFNGIKYEQSAAFAMIPSTT
>scaffold6778
EQSAAFAMIPSTTSISWRVLSTSFNGIKYEQ
>TLLD002_NODE_212
WRVLSTSFNGIKYEQSAAFAMIPSTT
>NODE_86667
EQSAAFAMIPSTTSISWRVLSTSFNGIKYEQ
```

With in-replace

```
$ perl -i -0777 -pe ' $x=$ARGV;$x=~s/\.faa//g; s/\>/>${x}_/ ' *faa
```

Files got modified

```
$ cat TLLD001.faa
>TLLD001_scaffold4567
WRVLSTSFNGIKYEQSAAFAMIPSTT
>scaffold0034
EQSAAFAMIPSTTSISWRVLSTSFNGIKYEQ
>scaffold7667
WRVLSTSFNGIKYEQSAAFAMIPSTT
>scaffold6778
EQSAAFAMIPSTTSISWRVLSTSFNGIKYEQ
$ cat TLLD002.faa
>TLLD002_NODE_212
WRVLSTSFNGIKYEQSAAFAMIPSTT
>NODE_86667
EQSAAFAMIPSTTSISWRVLSTSFNGIKYEQ
$
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its old but on the OSX vers of sed the `-i` option expects an extension. So, you need to add an `-e` argument and give `''` as an argument to `-i`.

```
for f in *.faa; do sed -i '' -e "s/^>/>${f%.faa}_/g" "${f}"; done
```

For the OSX folks out there :)